# How to order a table in a specific order based on condition of the table data in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

### My Issue:

I'm looking to order a table which I have set conditions on to display by a type. For example, I have conditions which make a row green, a row red, a row blue. I'd like to order these tables so it is displayed by green rows first, blue rows second and red rows third.  I'm creating the conditions by using razor c# to categorise them into their colour

### My Research:

I've searched and found unrelated issues. They're trying to tell me how to order things by descending or ascending order in terms of name etc. I cannot find a way to apply it to my conditions I have created.

### My Effort:

From the answer suggested:

```
public string BackgroundColour()
    {
        string colour = string.Empty;
        if (ExistsBothFolder && IsContentSame)
        {
            colour = "lightgreen";
        }
        else if (!HasSameContentWithAnotherFileName && !ExistsBothFolder && !IsContentSame && !IsDateModifiedSame)
        {
            colour = "lightcoral";
        }
        else if (ExistsBothFolder && !IsContentSame)
        {
            colour = "lightskyblue";
        }
        else if (HasSameContentWithAnotherFileName && !ExistsBothFolder)
        {
            colour = "orange";
        }
        return colour;
    }
```

In my view:

```
    @foreach (var fileDetail in Model.Folder1.FileDetails.OrderBy(fd => fd.BackgroundColour == "lightgreen"? 0: (fd.BackgroundColour == "lightcoral"? 1 : 2))){

    <td style="background-color: @fileDetail.BackgroundColour">
```

Doesn't let me use operators such as == in view to the method above?
Also the razor @ in the background colour isn't recognised for some reason and asks for a proper colour.

*(Had to delete the previous code since it said it wasn't properly formatted, refused to let me edit the post.)*

Comment: That `== true` all over the place is so annoying.

Comment: is there a better alternative i can use?

Comment: You don't need it at all, `(fileDetail.ExistsBothFolder == true & fileDetail.IsContentSame == false)` should be `(fileDetail.ExistsBothFolder && !fileDetail.IsContentSame)`

Comment: Also the `&` should be `&&`, otherwise it evaluates the right part even when the left part is already false.

Comment: i guess ive become so used to using it thanks

Comment: Is there a `foreach` or something above your code, that's what we need to figure out the ordering.

Comment: Yes, `@foreach (var fileDetail in Model.Folder1.FileDetails)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all those `if` conditions to the model. Your view should just have

```
<td style="background-color: @fildeDetail.BackgroundColor">
    @if (fileDetail.IsFolder )
    {
        <img alt="ListView" src="@Url.Content("https://s27.postimg.org/3ywaao4sz/new_Folder1.png")" style="width: 20px; height: 25px;" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img alt="ListView" src="@Url.Content("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/N/K/u/R/m/8/file-icon-md.png")" style="width: 20px; height: 25px;" />
    }
    <a href="#Section1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fileDetail.Name)</a>
</td>
```

Then you could change the order based in the `foreach` or in the model itself.

```
@foreach(var fileDetail in Model.Folder1.FileDetails
    .OrderBy(fd => fd.BackgroundColor == "green"? 0: (fd.BackgroundColor == "red"? 1 : 2)))
```

Although it just looks like a code smell, relying on color to set the order.

Comment: if i move it to models, what will the if statements return? how would you return a colour?

Comment: @someguy76 it would return a string which is the color, like "green".

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late, i put my logic into a managers folder where it takes 2 inputs to compare. My models just creates getters and setters to assign values to. Im not sure how i would place my if logics to return the colour string

Comment: I have tried to place it in my models and then use the order by function but it is just throwing me an error when i run that view page

Comment: It throws a compiler error when i try to use the == you used into the method i made called backgroundcolour

Comment: @someguy76 I'd have to see it, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Please check revised question

Comment: @someguy76 you made a method instead of a property. Either change it to a property or use `<td style="background-color: @fileDetail.BackgroundColour()">`

Comment: @someguy76 and fd.BackgroundColour() in the OrderBy

Comment: Thanks for this, but how would i order it by green first, blue second, orange third than red last? in the orderby line?

Comment: @someguy76 I'd actually add another property for the ordering which returns the order as an integer for example. 0 for green, blue 1, etc. Then your `OrderBy(fd => fd.MyOrderingProperty)`

Comment: i just did this, this works is it ok? `@foreach (var fileDetail in Model.Folder1.FileDetails.OrderBy(fd => fd.BackgroundColour() == "lightgreen"? 0: (fd.BackgroundColour() == "lightskyblue"? 1 : (fd.BackgroundColour() == "orange"? 2 : 3))))`

Comment: @someguy76 it's a little counter-intuitive that the order relies on the color. It's a code smell. I'd try and figure out a different way to do it.

Comment: Yes relies on the colour which is retrieved from that method based on its condition. thanks for the help and patience!